# Number validation using do while loop in C

Tags: c

I have this code which runs once; then I enter some non-number text and it keeps on printing out

> Enter Seed

without executing the `scanf` code.

```
do {
    printf("Enter SEED: ");
    scanf("%d", &seed);
}
while (!isdigit(seed));
```

Comment: @batbrat flushing stdin is undefined behaviour, unless specifically stated otherwise.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen if a non-number is entered? Where is the code that makes that happen? Also, what do you think your code does if `scanf` fails? It tests if `seed` is a digit whether or not it contains valid data?!

Comment: @self, removed. Flushing stdout isn't the right solution either, is it? I remember being taught to do that, but it's been a while since I've written code dealing with the scanf family of functions, stdin and stdout.

Comment: @batbrat Look at the best answer.

Comment: @self, thanks again. I did look at that, and looked up flushing buffers again. I understood the problem correctly, i.e. the newline would remain in the buffer, but attempted to solve it using something that clearly wouldn't work. I'm glad you caught this now, and I've unlearned the nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing newline from previous input is taken as new input, you need to eat that up

Avoid using `scanf` use `fscanf` instead :-

```
int seed, ch;
do{
    printf("Enter SEED: ");
    if(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &seed) == 1)
        break;
    else 
       while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); //Eat the trailing newline
}while(1);
```

Comment: is there any other way to eat the newline?

Comment: Why is `fscanf` better than `scanf` here?

Answer (score 1):

If `seed` is not an integer, it stays in the input buffer. `scanf("%d",&seed);` only takes `int` inputs from the input buffer. If user enters a `char` you will have to design some way to get rid of the char from the buffer.

```
do {
    printf("Enter SEED: ");
    scanf("%c", &seed);
}
while (!isdigit(seed)); //isdigit() checks if seed is '1', '2', ... , '9'
```